# How do i re-render and add more functions in an class based on ReactState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently trying to make a feature which will **add a counter function(`Increment +`) multiple times** following the click or increment in **react state** of **`Incrementor` button** without removing/resetting the previously added **`Increment +`** button.

**Example**- Currently `<Increment />` is called twice in the initial render of `Finalrender` **variable's** `sub-container` **class** *[Given in the shared code below]*. I want to add more of this same `<Increment />` along with the incremented display value of **`Incrementor`**. Means when the user will press on **`Incrementor`** button then a new **`Increment +`** section will be created to work independently.

### Now, How do i only re-render the `sub-container` with additional `<Increment/>` function call based on the **incremented react state number** of `Increment +` buttons.

**I have tried** using `append` function but as the react doesn't render those items that gets inserted later after rendering, it didn't work.
*Therefore Looking help from this community.*

#### Javascript -

```
const domContainer = document.getElementById("root");

// const content = "Hello World";

const Increment = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="display">{counter}</h1>
      <div>
        <button
          id="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setCounter(counter + 1);
          }}
        >
          Increment +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Incrementor = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div id="incrementorHolder">
      <h1 id="currentIncrementor">{counter}</h1>
      <div id="incrementorButtonHolder">
        <button
          id="incrementor"
          onClick={() => {
            setCounter(counter + 1);
          }}
        >
          Incrementor +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Finalrender = (
  <div id="maincontainer">
    <div className="container">
      <Incrementor />
    </div>
    <div className="sub-container">
      <Increment />
      <Increment />
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer).render(Finalrender);
```

#### HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./incrementor.js" type="text/babel" defer></script>
    <title>Incrementor</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```